# "Object reference not set" using FindControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to loop through my dropdown controls on my aspx page here is the code I have:

```
Private Sub PopulateDropDowns(ByVal dropDownName As String)

Dim dropDown As DropDownList = CType(Me.FindControl(dropDownName), DropDownList)

dropDown.Items.Add(New ListItem With {.Text = "Somedata", .Value = "123"})

End Sub
```

I'm getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Here is my aspx page (I've search through other answer which talk about the hierarchy of controls which I've tried - but failed)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="SelectTeam.aspx.vb" Inherits="FCO.SelectTeam" %>
```

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOpenBrd1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOpenBrd2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOpenBrd3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOpenBrd4" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` because **dropDown** is `NULL` or `NOTHING`. It is always good practice to check for NULL or NOTHING when you are dealing with objects.

When I need to find controls I always put them inside a `DIV` with `runat="server"` attribute, this way I know exactly where they are.

The following is *one way* of getting this to work:

### **ASPX:**

```
<div id="myControls" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOpenBrd1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOpenBrd2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOpenBrd3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOpenBrd4" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

### **VB.NET Code-Behind:**

```
Private Sub PopulateDropDowns(ByVal dropDownName As String)

    'Notice I am using "myControls" instead of "Me"
    Dim dropDown As DropDownList = CType(myControls.FindControl(dropDownName), DropDownList)

    If dropDown IsNot Nothing Then
        dropDown.Items.Add(New ListItem With {.Text = "Somedata", .Value = "123"})
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    PopulateDropDowns("ddOpenBrd1")    
End Sub
```

BTW, since each of your DropDownLists has `runat = "server"` then you should be able to add *items* to it directly, without needing to "find it" by doing something like:

```
ddOpenBrd1.Items.Add(New ListItem With {.Text = "Somedata", .Value = "123"})
```

Comment: Do they need to be initialized within a click event? I'm currently calling a private sub on page load...